# Why We Need EventArgs class in C#?

Tags: c#, delegates

I know that the purpose of `event` keyword just to used in pair with `+=` operator to make list of `delegate`. And when constructing delegate we can make any signature (of parameter) for method that compatible with that delegate.

For example I create  delegate

```
public delegate void StartEventHandler(object sender, StartEventArgs e);
```

with two parameter: the first with the type object and the second with the type `StartEventArgs`. But in many [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5043/Step-by-Step-Event-handling-in-C) that I found on the internet, the second parameter for that delegate must inherited [EventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) type. Why we do this instead to make the second parameter come/inherited from arbitrary type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't *need* to and I'm sure the code will still compile if you used an arbitrary base class but it is a convention.

Conventions are good because it makes it easier to understand for people who are not familiar with your code already. If I subscribe to an event in C# I expect a certain method signature.

It is also good because it makes different types of events interchangeable.

For example, say you have three delegates

```
public delegate void AEventHandler(object sender, AEventArgs e);
public delegate void BEventHandler(object sender, BEventArgs e);
public delegate void CEventHandler(object sender, CEventArgs e);
```

You could write a generic method that conforms to all three delegates because all the args objects inherit from the same base class.

```
public void eventMethod(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Any one of the events fired
}

public void subscribeToEvents() {
    eventA += new AEventHandler(this.eventMethod);
    eventB += new BEventHandler(this.eventMethod);
    eventC += new CEventHandler(this.eventMethod);
}
```

And even cast if you know what types to expect

```
public void eventMethod(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Any one of the events fired
    if (e is BEventArgs) {
        // Event type B fired
        var eventB = e as BEventArgs;
        eventB.doSomething()
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're able to use C# 7 the pattern matching switch will enable "casting if you know what types to expect".